# How do you disable all keys with jQuery except backspace?

Tags: jquery

I can successfully stop all keys from being pressed with:

`$this.keydown(false);`

How can I disable all keys with the exception of the backspace key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the `keyCode` of the event argument:

```
$this.keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode !== 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/kt69H/)

Comment: Don't know why they down voted you. It works, now I'm trying to disable all other keys accept backspace after three characters.

Comment: @TLav: Check `$this.val().length`, too.

Comment: This is what I have so far but its trippy...

    `$('#text').keyup(function(e) {
    var l = $(this).val().length;
    if(l == 3){
        $(this).keydown(false, function(e){
            if(e.keyCode !== 8) {
                e.preventDefault();
              }
        });
    }
})
`
I can't seem to type after hitting backspace
http://jsfiddle.net/tlaverdure/y84tu/

Comment: @TLav: Check it inside the handler with the `keyCode`: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/y84tu/1/ But if you just want to give your textbox a maximum length, that's exactly what the (much nicer) `maxlength` attribute was designed for: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/y84tu/2/

Comment: Haha... forgot about the maxlegnth attribute. Learning jQuery so I get into modes where I think everything needs to be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback, check the keycode of the pressed key, if it's the backspace key then allow it, otherwise block.